# How to change the src value of an video based on the options value in a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have an video tag and a select box.
My code:

```
<video src="default.mp4" id="videobox">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
 <select id="test">
        <option value="./A.mp4">A</option>
        <option value="./B.mp4">B</option>
        <option value="./C.mp4">C</option>
    </select>
```

I need to change the src value of the video tag based on the select box value.

If I select the option A the the value of the option A(./A.mp4) should fill in the src of the video.

I need to write jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select box onchange event will be trigger and video src attribute value will be updated accordingly on change of select box.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('video').attr('src',$("#test").val());
  $("#test").change(function(){
    $('video').attr('src',$(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video src="default.mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
<select id="test">
  <option value="./A.mp4">A</option>
  <option value="./B.mp4">B</option>
  <option value="./C.mp4">C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the change event of your select box, and then change the src attribute of your video based on the value selected like so:

```
$("#test").on("change", function() {
    $("video").attr("src", $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `onchange` for select.

```
$("#test").on("change", function() {
  $(this).prev().attr("src", $(this).val());
});
```